# Raspi not using IPv6-Interface-ID defined in router settings

Tags: raspbian, dhcp, ipv6

I'm trying to make my raspi available via dyndns over IPv6. I have the whole dyndns thing setup in my router and it works.

When trying to make the raspi itself available I can open up ports in my routers settings for IPv6. My router also defines an Interface-ID, which is (or rather should be) the second half of the IPv6 adress for the device. And the opened port only works for this IPv6 adresses with that Interface-ID.
[image]

My Problem now is the raspi does not really use this Interface-ID for its public ip address.
When I look into the ip settings of my rapsi it has two IPv6 adresses. A link local (FE80) that uses this interface id and a global (2a02) which does not.
[image]
And now I can't reach my raspi with the IPv6 adress it has. If I manually add the right global IP adress (with the interface-ID defined by my router) I can reach it but I don't want to add a static IPv6 since the IPv6-Prefix my router gets could change.

So I read about this SLAAC setting that seems to be responsible for this.
It is set to private by default which causes the IPv6 Interface-ID to be randomly generated.
But there are only two settings for this and the other one (hwaddr) generates the Interface-Id from the MAC-Adress which is also not what I want. (Is it even good practice to leak you MAC-Adress out in the Internet like this?)
But what I could not find is how to disable this whole thing in general and use the Interface-Id the router defines.
So how can I do this? Or am I missuderstanding something here?